# Create a 'Residual Property' from Alfresco REST API

Tags: javascript, rest, properties, alfresco

I'm using Alfresco REST API to upload files and add metadatas from a NodeJS application.

I was wondering if there was a way to create a 'Residual Property' with a simple rest request.

(By 'residual property' I mean a property without a model or an aspect).

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried simply adding a property that does not exist in the model? This should work.

http://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/concepts/metadata-model-props.html

> Although the content model provides the ability to specify property
>   definitions, the content repository supports a feature known as a
>   residual property, where a value can be set on a node for which there
>   is no associated property definition defined in a content model. This
>   allows for a node to act as a property bag for an arbitrary set of
>   named-value pairs.

Comment: Sadly, when I try to add a custom property in my request, I got the following message in return :

` {"error":{"errorKey":"Unknown property: customProp","statusCode":400,"briefSummary":"06060005 Unknown property: customProp", "StackTrace":"Pour des raisons de sécurité, le traçage de la pile n'est plus affiché, mais la propriété est conservée dans les versions précédente.","descriptionURL":"https://api-explorer.alfresco.com"}}`

Comment: Moreover, If I add a custom namespace before the property name, I got an error saying : 'bl:customProp isn't a valid QName. Namespace prefix bl is not mapped to a namespace URI'  :/